# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on javascript

Tags: javascript

Well, I'm trying make a countdown to Christmas and I'm getting this error
I'm new in this, please help

```
<script>
function Falta() {
var d = new Date();
var di = 25 - d.getDate();
var ho = 23 - d.getHours();
var mi = 59 - d.getMinutes();
var se = 59 - d.getSeconds();
var di = checkTime(di);
var ho = checkTime(ho);
var mi = checkTime(mi);
var se = checkTime(se);
var t = setTimeout(Falta(), 500)
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = di + ":" + ho + ":" + mi + ":" + se;
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
    return i;
}
</script>
<div id="demo" onclick="Falta()">Click!</div>
```

Comment: `Falta` is calling `Falta` recursively ...

Comment: That big wall of `var`s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes with your code.

- Missing semicolons.
- Inline event handlers (while it works, it's not recommended).
- Excecuting the `Falta()` function instead of just passing it by reference.
- Reuse of the `var` keyword once the variable has been set.

I've set up a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qqw8r88n/) with a working demo of your idea.

### HTML

```
<div id="demo">
  Click!
</div>
```

Simple and clean, no inline event handling, this allows to separate your *HTML* from your *JavaScript*.

### JavaScript

```
demoDiv = document.getElementById("demo"); //added a reference for the div
demoDiv.addEventListener("click",Falta); //added the onclick event

function Falta() {
  var d = new Date();
  var di = 25 - d.getDate();
  var ho = 23 - d.getHours();
  var mi = 59 - d.getMinutes();
  var se = 59 - d.getSeconds();
  di = checkTime(di); //removed var keywords
  ho = checkTime(ho);
  mi = checkTime(mi);
  se = checkTime(se);
  setTimeout(Falta, 500); //added semicolon, removed parenthesis
  demoDiv.innerHTML = di + ":" + ho + ":" + mi + ":" + se;
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  };
  return i;
}
```

So, first of all I've set up a reference for the `<div>` element since we'll be calling it a few times.

After that I've set the `click` event via the `addEventListener()` function, and passed the `Falta()` function as a reference (that would be without the parenthesis).

I've also removed the second `var` keywords you used while updating your variable names, it should only be use to declare a variable, not every time you change it's value.

Finally I passed the `Falta()` function to the `setTimeout()` as a reference, instead of executing it.

Hope this helps!

**Note:** it is worth noting that *JSFiddle* automatically wraps your code inside the `window.onload` event, and thus transferring your code to another enviroment may not work as it's not waiting for the *DOM* to load before searching for the `<div>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var t = setTimeout(Falta, 500)
```

instead. Note the call has no parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling the `Falta` every .5 seconds inside `Falta` method using `setTimeout` !

Remove this line from `Falta()` method.

```
var t = setTimeout(Falta(), 500)
```

Also, you are redeclaring some of your varibales(di,ho etc). If you want the count down timer to start automatically without the button click, you may have the `setTimeOut` expression outside of your `Falta()` method.

Here is the corrected code.

```
function Falta() {
    var d = new Date();

   var di = 25 - d.getDate();
   var ho = 23 - d.getHours();
   var mi = 59 - d.getMinutes();
   var se = 59 - d.getSeconds();
   di = checkTime(di);
   ho = checkTime(ho);
   mi = checkTime(mi);
   se = checkTime(se);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = di + ":" + ho + ":" + mi + ":" + se;
} 
//You can have the below line if you want the count down timer to start automatically.
var t = setTimeout(Falta(), 500);

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i;}
    return i;
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/xoduqik/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample

Answer (score 0):

You're *calling* the `Falta` function in you `setTimeout` function call; you need to pass the function name instead. Everything else is OK: Just change `var t = setTimeout(Falta(), 500)` to `var t = setTimeout(Falta, 500);`.

And do be careful with your semicolons, please.